# How to import module from node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Inside `node_modules` there is directory:

```
data/lib/
```

With files:

```
index.js
index.ts
Data.js
Data.ts
```

How to use this module using import?

I have tried:

```
import import * as d from  'data/lib';
```

I says that:

```
`index.d.ts' is not a module
```

File `index.d.ts' is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `index.d.ts` beside the `index.js`. You need to generate a build from your `.ts` files to be able to import it in other projects. There is a property on `tsconfig.json` called **declaration** that you can set to true, and then when you call `tsc` to generate your build, it will create the `.d.ts` files automatically for you. [Take a look](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).